# MQTT with Arduino ESP8266, can't publish to broker after a couple of publishes

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, sleep-mode

I am trying to implement MQTT with Arduino and ESP8266. The setup is supposed to publish to broker, go to sleep for some interval, then reset itself, so that the cycle continues.

The sketch:

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiEspClient.h>
#include <WiFiEspUdp.h>
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "LowPower.h"

IPAddress server(10, 8, 17, 14);
char ssid[] = "myssid";       
char pass[] = "pass";           
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;   

WiFiEspClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
SoftwareSerial soft(2,3); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  soft.begin(9600);
  WiFi.init(&soft);
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    while (true);
  }
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  client.setServer(server, 1883);
}

void(* resetFunc)(void)=0;

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  Serial.println("going to sleep");
  delay(500);
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_8S,ADC_OFF,BOD_OFF);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("resetting");
  delay(500);
  resetFunc();
}

void reconnect() {
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (client.connect("arduinoClient")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.publish("IITMandi","testing mqtt powersaver...");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

After a few publishes (the highest consecutive publishes I have seen is around 20), it is unable to publish more. The Nano doesn't get hot but the ESP gets hot.

Can anyone tell me what could be the cause?

[image: screenshot of Serial monitor]

Comment: maybe your mqtt server isn't giving up on your old connections quickly enough

Comment: Can you track down the `failed, rc = -2` line in the library code and figure out what error return code this is?

Comment: as the error code says there's an error connecting to the broker, you should alse look into the broker's log. I'm also suspecting something like @dandavis

Comment: to expand: if you reset quicker than your lifetime, you will rack-up connections. send mqtt a short life span when connecting

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, rc=-2 means, failed to establish connection to broker.

Comment: @dandavis, should I decrease my keepalive , or should I start a persistent session?

Comment: It's better to properly disconnect before going to sleep and set the session to persist.

Comment: @BMelis , I replaced `resetFunc()` inside the main loop with `client.loop()` ,tested it for around 8 hrs, seems to work fine .

Comment: @BMelis, is a persistent connection required for publishing the data? Persistent session are supposed to be there for subscribers ,who want their messages to be queued in the broker when they are offline, and be delivered to them when re establish the connection.

Answer (score -1):

I have been battling with the ESP8266 for about a week now so I feel like I got a feeling I know what your problem is. Your ESP8266 is probably fried, no fault to you. The cause of the failure is likely an internal diode that failed causing your device to have current issues. Depending on the manufacturer, the diode is not rated properly and shorts after a small period of usage. If it was a more instant failure, then it may be that your module cant handle the 5v DIO from the arduino. Good luck with this thing. It can be pretty finicky.